# Como guardar múltiples registros en una DB con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> Aclaro que esta pregunta puede ser un poco extensa, pido favor su comprensión, gracias.

Tengo un sitio en **Laravel** con **PHP** y una base de datos en **MySQL** en **PHPMyAdmin** en donde tengo una lista sobre unos complejos deportivos, la cual al seleccionar uno, me muestra sus canchas asociadas.

Luego se selecciona una opción y posteriormente la fecha y hora la cual son 2 de cada una respectivamente, es decir, una para el inicio de la fecha de reserva y otra para el término.

Lo mismo con los horarios, uno es para el inicio de la jornada y el otro para el término de ésta.

A continuación dejo un ejemplo, **similar** para que se entienda un poco mejor lo que tengo.

> Aclaro que no es el código que de verdad tengo es solo un ejemplo.

```js
function MostrarAutos(){
      
    var Club_1 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_club_1');
    var Club_2 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_club_2'); 
    var Club_3 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_club_3');
    var Club_4 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_club_4');
    var DiVLabelClub = document.getElementById('AutosDiv');
  

       
      if(document.bicis.SelectAutos.value == 'Club1'){
        
         DiVLabelClub.style.display = 'block';
         Club_1.style.display = 'block';
         Club_2.style.display = 'none';
         Club_3.style.display = 'none';
         Club_4.style.display = 'none';
            
      }else if(document.bicis.SelectAutos.value == 'Club2'){
          
         DiVLabelClub.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Club_2.style.display = 'block';
         Club_1.style.display = 'none';
         Club_3.style.display = 'none';
         Club_4.style.display = 'none';
        
  
            
      }else if(document.bicis.SelectAutos.value == 'Club3'){
          
         DiVLabelClub.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Club_3.style.display = 'block';
         Club_1.style.display = 'none';
         Club_2.style.display = 'none';
         Club_4.style.display = 'none';
            
            
      }else if(document.bicis.SelectAutos.value == 'Club4'){
          
         DiVLabelClub.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Club_4.style.display = 'block';
         Club_1.style.display = 'none';
         Club_2.style.display = 'none';
         Club_3.style.display = 'none';

            
       }else if(document.bicis.SelectAutos.value == ''){
          
         DiVLabelClub.style.display = 'none';
         Club_1.style.display = 'none';
         Club_2.style.display = 'none';
         Club_3.style.display = 'none';
         Club_4.style.display = 'none';
            
      }
   }
```

```css
#autos{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
#cuerpo{
   font-family: 'Segoe UI';
       
}  

#bici{
  width: 30%;
}
.fecha{
  
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5.4mm;
  left: 26mm;
}
#btn_enviar{

  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  width: 20%;
  outline-style: none !important;
  
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
#btn_enviar:hover{

  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.hora{

  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuerpo">
  <form action="#" method="POST" name="bicis">
  <h2>Arriendo de Clubes</h2>
  <label>Seleccione un club:</label>&nbsp;
  <select id="bici" name="SelectAutos" onchange="MostrarAutos()" required="required">
     <option value="">Seleccione...</option>

     <option value="Club1">Club 1</option>     
     <option value="Club2">Club 2</option>
     <option value="Club3">Club 3</option>
     <option value="Club4">Club 4</option>
   </select>
   
        
        <br><br>
        <div>
        
        <div id="AutosDiv" style="display: none;">
          <label>Seleccione un equipamiento.</label>
          <br>
        </div>
          <div id="Conjunto_club_1" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="1" id="id_1"/>
            <label>Balon de Basketball </label>
        
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="2" id="id_2"/>
            <label>Petos</label>
            <br>
          
          </div>
          
          <div id="Conjunto_club_2" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="3" id="id_3"/>
            <label>Raquetas</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="4" id="id_4">
            <label>Pelotas de Tenis</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="5" id="id_5">
            <label>Red</label>
          </div>
     
          <div id="Conjunto_club_3" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="6" id="id_6"/>
            <label>Red</label>
            <br>
          
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="7" id="id_7"/>
            <label>Petos</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="8" id="id_8">
            <label>Balon de Voleyball</label>
          </div>
          
          <div id="Conjunto_club_4" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="9" id="id_9"/>
            <label>Petos</label>
            <br>
          
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="10" id="id_10"/>
            <label>Casco</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="11" required="required" id="id_11">
            <label>Pisos de Goma Eva</label>
          </div>
          
        <br>
        <label>Seleccione la fecha de inicio:</label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" required="required"/>
        <br><br>
        <label>Seleccione la fecha de término:</label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" required="required"/>
        <br><br>
        <label>Seleccione un horario:</label>
        <br><br>
        
        <label>Desde:&nbsp;</label>
        
        <input type="time" name="desde" required="required" class="hora" step="3600">
        <label>&nbsp;Hasta:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="time" name="hasta" required="required" class="hora" step="3600">
        <br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="RESERVAR" id="btn_enviar">
      
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Ahora el tema es que no se como insertar múltiples registros dentro de mi tabla en mi base de datos.

Dejo la tabla.

**`TABLA HORARIO`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada checkbox corresponde a un id de la tabla cancha, pero se guardan en la tabla **`horario`** en el campo **`cancha_id`**. Es decir por ejemplo, usando el ejemplo que puse.

Si se selecciona el Club 1 y luego se selecciona todo el equipamiento. El resultado en la tabla horario sería el siguiente.

```
id|fecha_inicio        |fecha_fin           |estado_id|club_id
 1|2018-10-21 08:00:00 |2018-10-21 09:00:00 |       2 |      1
 2|2018-10-21 08:00:00 |2018-10-21 09:00:00 |       2 |      2
```

Donde **`club_id`** corresponde a cada checkbox seleccionado.

Del mismo modo para mi codigo verdadero es eso lo que quiero lograr. Que se ingresen múltiples registros dependiendo de cada checkbox seleccionado.

Si es 1 se ingresará sólo un registro, si son 2 los seleccionados serán 2 registros, y si son 3 serán 3 y así sucesivamente.

Siendo los mismos valores para los campos pero diferente **`id`**, y diferente **`cancha_id`** si se puede de manera casi automática.

Pero no se muy bien cómo hacerlo.

Dejo el código que tengo.

**`MI CONTROLADOR`**

```
public function store(Request $request){

    try{

      foreach ($request->get('sel') as $key => $value) {

            $horarios = new HorariosNew();
            $horarios->id = $request->get('id')[$key];


            $horarios->hora_inicio = $request->get('desde')[$key].' '.$request->get('sel')[$key];

            $horarios->hora_fin = $request->get('hasta')[$key].' '.$request->get('sel2')[$key];
            $horarios->estado_horario_id = $request->get('estado_horario_id')[$key];
            $horarios->cancha_id = $request->get('check')[$key];
            $horarios->save();
        }




    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');

         return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

    }

        Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
        return redirect()->route('horarios.store');

    }
}





/*---------------------------------*/
```

**`MI VISTA`**

```
@extends('layouts.template')
@section('titulo')
@endsection

@section('content')

<div role="main">
    <div>
        <div> 
            <h4>Agregar un nuevo Horario</h4>
            <h6> Debe rellenar los campos solicitados</h6>

            {!! Form::open(['route'=> 'horarios.store','method'=> 'POST','name'=>'horario', 'id'=>'horario_id', 'files' => true] ) !!}

            <div>
                /*ID DE LA TABLA HORARIO*/
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$last_horario['id']}}" name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[id]">
                <label>Complejos</label>
                <br>
                <label style="color: grey;">Seleccione un complejo</label>
                <br>


                /*SELECT DE LOS COMPLEJOS*/
                <select id="complejos" name="SelectComplejos" required="required" onchange="MuestraCanchas(event)">

                    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>

                    @foreach($complejo as $complejo)
                    <option value="{{$complejo->id}}" name="ListaComplejos">{{$complejo->nombre}}
                    </option>   

                    @endforeach
                </select>



               /*CHECKBOX QUE CORRESPONDE A CADA CANCHA_ID RESPECTIVAMENTE*/
                <br><br>
                    <div class="DivCheckCanchas" id="DivCheckCanchas">
                        <label id="label_check">*&nbsp;Seleccione una cancha o campo</label>
                    <br><br>
                    @foreach($campos as $campos)
                    <div id="DivCanchas" class="DivCanchas">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-complejo="{{$campos->complejo_id}}" id="{{$campos->nombre}}" value="{{$campos->id}}" name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[check]">
                        <label id="LabelCanchas" style="color: grey;" for="{{$campos->nombre}}">{{$campos->nombre}}</label>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                  </div>


                /*SELECT DE LAS FECHAS*/
                <br>
                <label>FECHAS</label>
                <br><br>
                <div class="input-daterange input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">DESDE</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[desde]" id="desde" required="required" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">HASTA</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[hasta]" id="hasta" required="required"/>
                </div>


                /*SON 2 SELECT DE LOS HORARIOS*/
                <br><br>
                <label>HORARIO DE INICIO</label>
                <label style="margin-left: 9cm;">HORARIO DE TERMINO</label>
                <br><br>
                <label>Seleccione una hora</label>
                <label style="margin-left: 8.45cm;">Seleccione una hora</label>
                <br>



                <select name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[sel]" id="options" required="required" class="option">
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                    <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
                    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                    <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                    <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                    <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                    <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                    <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                    <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                    <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
                </select>


                /*2DO SELECT*/
                <select name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[sel2]" id="options2" required="required" class="option2">
                    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                    <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                    <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                    <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                    <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                    <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                    <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                    <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
                    <option value="24:00:00">24:00:00</option>
                </select>



                /*ESTADO DEL HORARIO*/
                <br><br><br>
                <label>Estado</label>
                <br>

                <input type="text" value="{{$last_horario['estado_horario_id']}}" maxlength="1" required="required" name="data_{{$last_horario['id']}}[estado_horario_id]">
                <br><br>


                /*SUBMIT*/
                <input type="submit" id="btn-success" value="REGISTRAR">

                <a href="{{URL::previous()}}">
                    <input type="button"  id="btn-cancelar" value="CANCELAR">
                </a>
                <br><br>
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el input que quieras poner mas de un valor asigna el atributo name como array

```
<input type="text" name="cancha_id[]" value="{{$loop->cancha_id}}">
```

Si haces en tu controlador un `print_r($request->cancha_id)` tendras un resultado similar

```
Array ( [0] => '1' [1] => '2' [2] => '3' [3] => '4' )
```

Asi que solo te quedaria recorrer en un loop `$request->cancha_id` y hacer la logica que desees con los id de cada uno

Comment: Ya veo, actualicé la pregunta mencionando como lo hice.